# Do bigger buttons improve usability and how they correspond with design? [case]

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons, design-patterns, style-guide

We're trying to incorporate a style guide which helps developers understand and build CSS across different resolutions. After reading these:

1. https://uxplanet.org/buttons-in-ui-design-the-evolution-of-style-and-best-practices-56536dc5386e (Nick Babich)
2. https://builttoadapt.io/intro-to-the-8-point-grid-system-d2573cde8632 (8pt grid system)
3. https://uxplanet.org/7-rules-for-mobile-ui-button-design-e9cf2ea54556
4. https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/
5. Bootstrap, Foundation, iOS and Material Design guidelines

I came to a question do bigger buttons on 1920x1080 (desktop) and above improve usability and do they ruin or fit into design at the same time? Is there any standard rule/research on this topic or does it apply only to particular scenarios?

> **[CASE]** Our case is a website for a car dealer whose main clients group is consisted of 40+ years old businessmen leasing the vehicles.
>   On the other hand, we want to build a site that also attracts younger
>   group so poor eyesight shouldn't be a factor. **In the end, we get to
>   the question above - does it improve the design in terms of usability
>   or not?**
>
> (the red frame is a full HD viewport)
>
> [image: buttons dimension]
>
> [image: buttons compared]

Comment: You might want to check out [Fitts' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law), which describes the relationship between target size, distance to the target, and speed of use. [This site includes a cool demonstration.](http://simonwallner.at/ext/fitts/)

Comment: Woah! That's something! Definitely gonna test it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If your buttons are bigger users will be able to select them faster which increases usability**

This is actually a law! It was proven by Paul Fitts in 1954. [Fitts's Law](https://www.lri.fr/~mbl/ENS/FONDIHM/2013/papers/Fitts-JEP54.pdf) provides a mathematical model which can accurately predict the amount of time taken to move to and select a target. Although, originally developed for movement in the physical world, UX practitioners successfully apply it to graphical user interfaces using a mouse cursor or other pointers.

[image]

Basically, the Fitts's Law states:

> The time to acquire a target is a function of the distance to and
>   size of the target.

- The higher the distance between the mouse cursor and
  the target button the more time it will take for the button to be
  selected.
- The smaller the size of the target button the slower the selection
  will be.

This basically means **bigger click area = faster selection times**.
However, don't be tempted to use Gorilla buttons covering half of the screen.

**Advice: use bigger button size's in higher screen resolutions**

In higher resolutions (>=1080p) the buttons and UI elements appear small. Thus, the time to select them and the effort is higher, which decreases the usability. So, it is a good idea to increase the size of buttons and other controls for higher screen resolutions.

Comment: +1. I thought that almost any UX developer or designer knew Fitt's law, since it is basic to this discipline. Until last month that I was part of a panel at a UX conference and most of the attendees were completely unaware of the existence of it, or how to use it.

Comment: @Devin True, true, same thing here. People claim to be experienced UX-ers but haven't heard of basic stuff, like Hick's, and Fitts's law.

Comment: Has anyone seen this in practice? I'd love to see some examples of UI affordances like buttons scaling up.

Comment: @MikeM I don't know about such studies, but you can use a click heatmaps to see how much area accidental click outside of the button area are there in the different screen resolutions.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov thanks for such comprehensive answer, this is exactly what I was looking for (also, a good explanation of Fitts's and Hick's laws: http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/fitts-law-hicks-law/). Although, it raised another question: where's the sweet spot, the equlibrium, of the size to aesthetics proportions - as the above graph shows, there's no much improvement between the biggest circles.

Comment: If we take 8pt grid rule + iOS guideline, can we assume going from 8pt padding, 16px font, 48px height on mobile through 24px padding, 20px font, 56px height on laptops to 40px padding, 24px font, 64px height on large desktops as a proper one? Does it apply to Fitt's law? What do You think?

Comment: @psoiree Fitts's law basically says the bigger your buttons the faster they would be selected. I cannot tell you exact dimensions to use and whether the one's you've pointed out will have good usability. You just have to go through the different resolutions and look for buttons and controls that appear too small and make them bigger, that's it. Otherwise, we need to do a nice study with click heatmaps if we want to give exact dimensions to use for the different resolutions.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov seems like a way to go - we'll definitely install a heatmap on this site. Will get back to you with results, guys.

Comment: Don't forget about design considerations. The role of a particular button may benefit from accent colors or other minor adjustments based on its position or importance on the page. For instance, the button for selecting a vehicle may need to be less prominent than one for "compare vehicles" or "buy now" etc.

Answer (score 1):

> came to a question do bigger buttons on 1920x1080 (desktop) and above improve usability

Bigger area to click -> better usability

> and do they ruin or fit into design at the same time?

They look less aesthetic, they look heavy and slow, i wouldn't use big fat buttons on a ferrari website but when it comes to a SUV website they might fit.

Just a question: have you tested that? Why do you think 40 year old man have problems interacting with a 20px button?

When it comes to tapping on the other hand, 40px tappable area is recommended.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I did NOT say that and I'm not against 40 years old men and their eyesight problems! (just kidding ;p) To be honest, we had signs the chairman of the company could have problems with them and overall he wants everything as big as possible - we're preparing an explanation why smaller buttons aren't the issue and they look better, one of the reasons why I'm looking for sources. There's a standard for mobiles, as You noticed, but noone says anything about big desktops - I assume it's more of an aesthetics problem then.

Comment: If you have a lot of resources and want to focus on the best usability you can provide your visitors the option to change the sizing of text and/or overall site elements, that would mean that you need to layout a few more options for different sized text/buttons, that way you would not restrict any user but provide additional UX to people which like it bigger. 

My mother has an eye-illness and she usually puts her browser to around 200% sizing, everything looks ultra bad for people like me, but that does not matter since she's able to browse... even if its still hard.

Comment: Definitely a good point. Although we're creating this style guide to be more efficient in terms of time instead of adding another layer of UX option. The thing is that when it goes to aesthetics the bigger buttons look better on most of the sections, especially the ones with only one single CTA. A small thing became a big dillema.

Comment: "*They look less aesthetic, they look heavy and slow...*" I get where you're coming from, but I think that's just one opinion. One example of, IMO, a really well-designed (both aesthetically and functionally) is [TurboTax](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/wheres-my-refund/). They use buttons of several sizes, but I'd describe most of them as medium to large. I wouldn't say that this single factor takes away from the site at all... In fact, I'd say the opposite--it helps to create a clear pathway for the user, almost as if the size corresponds to the likeliness of it being what I need.

Comment: Now, certainly large buttons don't fit well in every site design, but think they can be very effective in appropriate contexts.

Comment: Its not even about the site design but also the product and message you are trying to deliver, thats why i used the car example.. brand message is really important too. Im not saying big buttons cant look good.